# Pytest-html: Customize report title based on marks

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I want to indicate the pytest test execution marks in the pytest-html report title
I am trying the approach as shown below. It does not work.

conftest.py

```py
#add test execution mark as a 'label' field to the report
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    if item.config.getoption("-m"):
        report.label = item.config.getoption("-m")

#add 'label' field to the title
def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    mark = report.label if hasattr(report, "label") else ""
    report.title = f"My Software: {mark} Test Report"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding label  as an attribute to pytest in pytest_configure hook:

```py
#add test execution mark as a 'label' field to the pytest namespace
def pytest_configure(config):
    pytest.label = config.getoption("-m")

#add 'label' field to the title
def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    report.title = f"My Software: {pytest.label} Test Report"
```